# Translation of "Break" in the sentence "How was your winter break"

Tags: traducción, definiciones

I always have trouble figuring out what break is in Spanish for the sentence "How was you winter break". I don't know if it break is vacaciones in this case. My guess is

> Como es tu invierno

Comment: Welcome to our site. We're a little strict on our translation requests, so that we don't turn into a translation service. We are happy to *help* you translate sentences, in the spirit of helping you learn the Spanish language, but we require that all translations requests show at least an attempt to translate the phrase into Spanish first. What have you come up with that we can help you clarify?

Comment: Do you mean that in my question, it should tell what I think the translation would be

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. We need to know that you've done your own research, and that you aren't just using us as a translation service.

Comment: Thanks. I have one question, my question that I asked was already answered, so why do I need to edit it again?

Comment: On Stack Exchange, we strive to make our content useful to future visitors. This means it's important to that our questions and answers fit a particular format, so that it's easy for future visitors to search for information that can help them.  Of course, nobody is obligating you to edit your question. If you have already answered your question, and choose not to edit your question, that's your choice. That means it will remain closed. That can be acceptable for some people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Literally it would be

> ¿Cómo fueron tus vacaciones de invierno?

Break normally is translated as "vacaciones" into Spanish, which is more like *holidays*.

As a remark, we rarely say "vacaciones de invierno", at least in Spain, we always say **vacaciones de Navidad** (Christmas Holidays).

Answer (score 2):

We translate "break" (the time for resting during vacations) as "vacaciones". The phrase whould be translated as :

> ¿Qué tal fueron tus vacaciones?

Note that we use "vacaciones" as a plural, cause is a sum of many days.

Comment: Thanks for the help but why is there a qué tal? I thought that qué tal means how are you.

Comment: no, it means "how is", we use, however, "¿Qué tal?" as a shortening of "¿Qué tal estás?" wich means "how are you?". 
You should'nt use "Que tal?" alone, as it doesnt have meaning alone, but we use it as a shorter version of "Que tal estás?"

Comment: "¿Qué tal te ha salido el exámen?" - "How did the exam go?"
"¿Que tal me queda el vestido?" - "How is this dress suiting me?"

Answer (score 2):

Break means **descanso** but depending on the context and the length of that break you can translate it as **vacaciones** (when it is a long period such as Christmas, Easter), **recreo**(when children at school take their break) o **pausa** (when you go for a coffee or lunch in the middle of your workday).

Answer (score 0):

**Receso** es la traduccion exacta de break en este contexto.

Como estuvo tu receso de invierno.

Answer (score -3):

How was your winter break = Como fueron tus vacaciones de invierno?